# Embedding PDF in WP 7.1 apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pdf, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing WP7 app with cheatsheets. Is there any C# component or library to embed PDF files in WP7 Mango apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component One have a control which will allow you to do this.
It's part of their [Studio for Windows Phone](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWindowsPhone/).

Comment: Do you have experience with Component One?

Comment: @Kir no, nut have seen the review at http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2011/05/14/Display-PDFs-in-your-Windows-Phone-7-application.aspx